# C# httpwebresponse stream - get text between tags (regex)

Tags: c#, regex, httpwebresponse

I'm currently using httpwebrequest & httpwebresponse to extract innerhtml from a webpage, but I'm trying to extract specific data between tags..

for example -

```
 <script>

 RESPONSIVE = {
     example: 'Hello world',
     name: 'Example',
     id: '32',
 };

 </script>
```

and what I'm trying to extract from that specific tag is the text within the

```
name:
```

tag

ie,

```
Example
```

would it would be possible for me to do something like if string starts with name: ' and ends in ', get inner content?

Comment: Use htmlagilitypack or similar libraries to get to the script tag, the rest is string parsing

Comment: @rene i asked for regex because I don't want to use htmlagilitypack :/ thanks for suggestion though

Comment: is XElement (from System.Xml.Linq) an option?
do you know the format and the names of the tags beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex for your task could look like this:
`^\s*(?<name>\w+): '(?<value>.*)',?$`

You can try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/jqZfqj/2